# <br/> not being displayed on text string replacement and then put into placeholder

Tags: c#, string, placeholder

When I read in the data from SQL it has \r\n for the carriage returns, so I use .Replace to convert the \r\n's to `<br/>`'s but on display the `<br/>`'s are ignored.  It works if I replace the \r\n's with `<p></p>` but this is not what I need.

The `<br/>`'s are being ignored and I need them to produce a newline.

Any insight as to why it is doing this or how to achieve what I am looking to do would be great!

EDIT: I've addressed the typo in the code below - but that isn't my question -at all-. I've asked about BR's and them displaying.

### HTML

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

### CODE-BEHIND

```
string strTempDetail = myReader["Detail"].ToString();
string strMoreTempDetail = strTempDetail.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
LiteralControl UserControlSpecialOffers = new LiteralControl(strMoreTempDetail.ToString());
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(UserControlSpecialOffers);
```

Thanks!

Comment: So your problem has nothing to do with SQL or `string.Replace`. It's strictly that linebreaks aren't showing up in your output when you expect them to, right?

Comment: Not related to your question, but why are you calling `ToString()` on a string?

Comment: @Dave - I like to do it for everything so there's no confusion on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else had modified the css file and put BR display:none; in the CSS. Of all the places!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code. You are assigning the original string into your control instead of the string containing your replacements.

change

```
LiteralControl UserControlSpecialOffers = new LiteralControl(strTempDetail.ToString());
```

to

```
LiteralControl UserControlSpecialOffers = new LiteralControl(strMoreTempDetail );
```

Comment: Typo updated. As my question didn't pertain to at all to the typo, please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong string in this line

```
LiteralControl UserControlSpecialOffers = new LiteralControl(strTempDetail.ToString());
```

it should be

```
LiteralControl UserControlSpecialOffers = new LiteralControl(strMoreTempDetail);
```

Comment: Why are you using .ToString() on a string?

Comment: @Babak just fixing the obvious error. Having .ToString() on the end is not needed but it's not why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're adding `strTempDetail` to your literal control, not `strMoreTempDetail`, which is the string where you performed the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any change reading your string from SQL Server? If had issues where a string read from an SQL server ntext column contained a '\n' instead of '\r\n' (even though '\r\n' was saved).

Try if `string strMoreTempDetail = strTempDetail.Replace("\n", "<br/>")` provides better results.

Or to be on the save side, replace both: `string strMoreTempDetail = strTempDetail.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>").Replace("\n", "<br/>")`

Comment: I've tried both of these. For some reason, the output of the placeholder will not output a newline to the browser. I will show a <p> however! which is very frustrating...

Comment: ..and yes this is output from SQL and it is in a nvarchar field.

Comment: Or use strTempDetail.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />")